# Hard Lefschetz for cycles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology, hodge-theory, intersection-theory

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over a field $k$. It is known by work of Deligne, that the Lefschetz operator:
$$
L^k:H^{2n-2k}\left(X_{\overline{k}},\mathbf{Q}_{\ell}\right)\to H^{2n+2k}\left(X_{\overline{k}},\mathbf{Q}_{\ell}(k)\right)
$$
is an isomorphism.

$L$ is the class of a hyperplane section in $H^2\left(X_{\overline{k}},\mathbf{Q}_{\ell}(1)\right)$.

Let $C^n(X)$ be the image of the group of codimension $n$ cycles into $H^{2n}\left(X_{\overline{k}},\mathbf{Q}_{\ell}(n)\right)$ under the cycle map:
$$
c^n:Z^n(X)\to H^{2n}\left(X_{\overline{k}},\mathbf{Q}_{\ell}(n)\right)
$$

> Is it known that $L^k$ also induces an isomorphism $C^{n-k}(X)\to C^{n+k}(X)$?

This is Conjecture $A(X)(b)$ in Grothendieck's [paper](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Eleila.schneps/grothendieckcircle/StandardConjs.pdf) on the standard conjectures. Conjecture $A(X)(a)$ is known by work of Deligne, so I am asking if Conjecture $A(X)(b)$ is also known (and on what fields $k$).

Comment: It is not known.